# Eclipse Kepler not able to organize favorites of my debug configs

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler and I got problems to configure my debug configurations.

I use about 50 debug configs that are available under "debug as..."-> context menu.
Now I have added successfull a new one that was placed at the end of the list(context menu).
Unfortunality I have to use this debug configuration very often.
Every time I have to scroll down to the bottom of the context menu to execute the debug run and that is very exhausting.

If I try to manage that problem via "organize favorites" I have the problem that I am not able to move up my debug configuration to the beginning of the list. The "up" Button is active but without any effect.

[image]

What did I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this on 4.4 M5 and it seems to work OK for me. Which version of Eclipse are you using ?